# How to detect what shell is running in Emacs comint-mode?

Tags: emacs

I have a shell in Emacs but `major-mode` gives me just `comint-mode`.
Is there a way to determine which type of shell?

Maybe what Emacs function was called to start it?
Or at least what is the interpreter's executable file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>M-:</kbd>`(process-command (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))`

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, when using a standard shell

```
echo $0
```

might be sufficient.

Comment: You can have not only standard system shells running in Emacs

Comment: @Sergey Thanks pointing at, will correct the answer a little bit.